# Decal render layer not working

Tags: unity

I’m projecting a pee decal on hydrant but its reflecting also on player body.
Tried to set decal render layers on projector and meshes but it doesn’t change anything.

Here is a few pictures of my configs.
Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by re-installing and re-configuring URP renderer from scratch.